# How to fix visual differences of responsive code in Safari and Chrome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, safari

I'm learning responsive coding currently but I seem to have run into a small problem I can't figure out. I'm using bootstrap framework.

In working on a site, I realized that that there are some differences when viewed on Safari. Chrome looks as I intended it to be, but on Safari the header shifts. The horizontal orange bar the nav sits on shifts upwards, and the short vertical orange bar jumps to the middle of the screen. However this only occurs at the large size. All other window sizes look fine.

I tried adjusting margins and padding for the large media query but then that also affects it in chrome and thus offsetting it. How should I go about fixing this problem without affecting other browsers?

The website is www.jennytaingdesign.com

and if the files are needed, it can be downloaded at https://www.dropbox.com/s/7a74id4f9k141m6/jennytaing_responsive.zip?dl=0

Any suggestions or answers would be very greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your website have some issues:

- The header width should be fluid, don't provide it with fixed width.
- You don't have to use two logos, for desktop and mobile. Instead, you can use one logo and adjust the img width as you want
- The header should contain the following: logo, navbar and the orange lines. In your case, it only contain the logo.
- You can create the desired effect of the orange lines by using a div with a specific height and :before pseudo element.
- You don't have to provide the ul menu a margin in each breakpoint, you can provide that in the main CSS file and it will be applied to the whole project.

I worked a little bit on the header and now it's like the note #3. Here is the update code:

```
<header>
    <a href="index.html" class="logo"><img src="img/header/logo.png" alt="logo" class="hidden-xs" id='logoDesktop'></a>     
    <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html" id="homeIcon"><span>HOME</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="portfolio.html" id="portfolioIcon">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html" id="contactIcon">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>

   <div class="test"></div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    position: relative;
}

header .test {
    background: #ED6643;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}

header .test:before {
    content: "";
    width: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #ED6643;
    left: 0;
    top: 92px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Please find [this](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/tv33tnlc4pruirb/AADjdd8dujgKFGPHkF6DEc5Ma?dl=0) link for the updated files

It now works on both Chrome and Safari.